# ios defaulting to music in control centre

Tags: iphone, ios, podcasts, control-center

I was wondering if there was a way to prevent the control centre from defaulting to music.

I listen to a lot of podcasts and I’ve tried various apps including Apple Podcasts to see if the following problem can be remedied but nothing works.

I often find that after pausing a podcast I return to the control centre and it has defaulted to music when I go to tap play. This can happen after as little as half an hour, sometimes it can be several hours, sometimes it doesn’t happen at all no matter how long it has been left.

To be clear, the apps are not crashing, they are still open in the background most often.

Answer (score 1):

Use Siri Shortcuts. One built-in command is to say "Podcasts" and Siri will resume media playback in the Podcasts app. If you want more specific podcast shortcuts, look into Overcast.